# What are the advantages of Fenrir's combos?

Tags: smite

I've been playing as Fenrir a lot over the past week (mainly because it is on the current free rotation).  With Fenrir being a lot more common, I have noticed that players mainly use one of these two combos:

- 1 - 2 - 3
- 3 - 2 - 1 (my preferred)

So far I would say one combo is about as common as the other.  Are there any advantages to using one combo over the other?

I found 3 - 2 - 1 useful because I can use 1 to escape if things go wrong.  Beyond that I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first combo (1.**Unchained** - 2.**Seething Howl** - 3.**Brutalize**) does allow for huge amounts of burst damage. You chase down and enemy(or join a team fight) with Unchained, buff yourself with Seething Howl and, hopefully, land 4 big hits on an enemy. That can easily kill characters with low health pools or low health due to damage they have already taken. A downside is that you don't have a way of escaping until you can use Unchained again.

The second combo I don't particularly like or get why you would do it. 2.**Seething Howl** is a damage buff, so if you are using Unchained as a means of escape you are rendering your buff useless. A possible use for that combo is if someone manages to escape your Brutalize. Then you can easily finish them off with a buffed Unchained.

I prefer initiating with a Brutalize on flanked enemies but that depends on your positioning and the ability to get to lone players. Fenrir is a single-target damage hero, so you should focus on doing big bursts of damage and leaving the fight as fast as possible. 2-3-1 is also a valid option since it starts with a buffed, high-damage ability and leaves Unchained for chasing or escape.

Comment: You are correct, if I use Seething Howl, it is wasted if I then need to escape.  I'll have to try 2-3-1 out.

Comment: Oh, and also Ragnarok can really help with that getting a player away from their team thing(or bringing them to your own tower for some extra damage).